# Have waf command use targets from a different waf command

Tags: waf

Here's a wscript:

```py
def build(bld):
    bld.recurse('somefolder')

def test(ctx):
    ctx(features='test ...', ..., use=['lib'])

from waflib.Build import BuildContext
class TestCtx(BuildContext):
    cmd = 'test'
    fun = 'test'
```

`lib` is a target created by some recursion into `somefolder` (perhaps in a subfolder). I want to use that in the `test` command. Can I do this without modifying the `wscript`(s) in `somefolder/**`? If so, how?

Alternatively, is there any way to make conditional the execution path of the `build` function to emulate the desired behavior (i.e. calling `waf build` and `waf test` would behave as desired)?

### Notes

I've tried using `ctx.recurse('somefolder',name='build')` in `test`, but the recursion from `somefolder` on doesn't penetrate subfolders of `somefolder`, and all `recurse` calls from within `somefolder` recurse as `test`.

Comment: Maybe try putting `ctx.fun = build` before calling `recurse` inside `test`. (Should work but I didn't test it.)